# Spartacus Single Step Checkout goes in a loop

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to convert our spartacus app to use a single step checkout.  I followed the instructions in https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/extending-checkout/.

The following is my app.module.ts configuration:

```
      routing: {
        routes: {
          checkout: {
            paths: ['checkout'],
          },
          // Add a new route for the combined step
          checkoutSinglePageCheckout: {
            paths: ['checkout/single-page-checkout'],
          },
        },
      },
      checkout: {
        steps: [
          {
            id: 'singleStepCheckout',
            name: 'checkoutProgress.singleStepCheckout',
            routeName: 'checkoutSinglePageCheckout',
            type: [CheckoutStepType.SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
                  CheckoutStepType.DELIVERY_MODE,
                  CheckoutStepType.PAYMENT_DETAILS,
                  CheckoutStepType.REVIEW_ORDER]
          },
        ],
      },
```

I have omitted the cmscomponents mapping, as I believe that may not be causing this issue.

This is my impex for the single-step-checkout route:

```
$contentCatalog=electronics-spaContentCatalog
$contentCatalogName=Electronics spa Content Catalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Online])[default=$contentCatalog:Online]

INSERT_UPDATE ContentPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;masterTemplate(uid,$contentCV);label;defaultPage[default='true'];approvalStatus(code)[default='approved'];homepage[default='false']
                         ;;CheckoutSingleStepCheckout;Checkout Single Step Checkout Page;MultiStepCheckoutSummaryPageTemplate;/checkout/single-step-checkout

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;cmsComponents(uid, $contentCV)
                         ;;BodyContentSlot-CheckoutSingleStepCheckout;Checkout Single Step Checkout;CheckoutProgressComponent,CheckoutProgressMobileTopComponent,CheckoutShippingAddressComponent,CheckoutDeliveryModeComponent,CheckoutPaymentDetailsComponent,CheckoutProgressMobileBottomComponent
                         ;;SideContentSlot-CheckoutSingleStepCheckout;Order Summary Slot;CheckoutOrderSummaryComponent
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];position[unique=true];page(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true];contentSlot(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true]
                                ;;BodyContent-CheckoutSingleStepCheckout;BodyContent;CheckoutSingleStepCheckout;BodyContentSlot-CheckoutSingleStepCheckout
                                ;;SideContent-CheckoutSingleStepCheckout;SideContent;CheckoutSingleStepCheckout;SideContentSlot-CheckoutSingleStepCheckout
```

I am not sure why it exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Did you have check your 'CheckoutGuard' ? Maybe you set some configuation that ends in a loop by the guard.

Comment: I didn't add a CheckoutGuard.  I have provided all the configuration that I did.

Comment: There is a default CheckoutGuard. Maybe you have to adapt it.

Comment: At the same time, this is from [this link](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/extending-checkout/) :  With a single-step checkout, you can set all components on this checkout route and remove the CheckoutGuard from the component configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by using an impex as follows:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ContentPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;masterTemplate(uid,$contentCV);label;defaultPage[default='true'];approvalStatus(code)[default='approved'];homepage[default='false']
                         ;;CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails;Checkout Single Page Checkout Details Page;MultiStepCheckoutSummaryPageTemplate;/checkout/single-step-checkout

INSERT_UPDATE CMSFlexComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;flexType
                              ;;CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetailsComponent;CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetailsComponent;CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;cmsComponents(uid, $contentCV)
                         ;;BodyContentSlot-checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails;Checkout Single Page Checkout Details Slot;CheckoutProgressComponent,CheckoutProgressMobileTopComponent,CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetailsComponent,CheckoutProgressMobileBottomComponent
                         ;;SideContentSlot-checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails;Order Summary Slot;CheckoutOrderSummaryComponent
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];position[unique=true];page(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true];contentSlot(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true]
                                ;;BodyContent-checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails;BodyContent;CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails;BodyContentSlot-checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails
                                ;;SideContent-checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails;SideContent;CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails;SideContentSlot-checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails
```

Here few things have to be noted:

1. The Content Page uid must be same as flexType in CMSFlexComponent
2. The flexType value (same as content page uid) should not be same as
   uid and name in CMSFlexComponent
3. I think ContentSlot uid, ContentSlotForPage uid also follows some
   naming condition.

Now I can do this configuration change in app.module.ts

```
      routing: {
        routes: {
          // Add a new route for the combined step
          checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails: {
            paths: ['checkout/single-step-checkout'],
          },
        },
      },
      checkout: {
        steps: [

          {
            id: 'singlePageCheckoutDetails',
            name: 'checkoutProgress.singlePageCheckoutDetails', // Provide translation for this key
            routeName: 'checkoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails',
            // This step sets both the delivery mode and the payment details, so you have to define both of these types
            type: [
              CheckoutStepType.SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
              CheckoutStepType.DELIVERY_MODE,
              CheckoutStepType.PAYMENT_DETAILS,
              CheckoutStepType.REVIEW_ORDER,
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
```

Now in my own single-page-checkout.module.ts, I use the following mapping:

```
export const singleStepCheckoutConfig = {
  cmsComponents: {
    CheckoutSinglePageCheckoutDetails: {
          component: SingleStepCheckoutComponent
    }
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SingleStepCheckoutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ConfigModule.withConfig(singleStepCheckoutConfig),
  ],
  entryComponents: [SingleStepCheckoutComponent]
})
```

[image: Single Page Checkout Combined Page]

Now my question is do I have to write all the angular components copying/extending from existing ones.  Mapping existing angular and CMS components don't work.

Comment: Are you able get the answer for it. I tried same, Combined steps are not visible in mapped angular. Is there any other approach achieved it for single step checkout? Tried same documentation, Showing empty as in above screenshot.@Mahesh

Comment: it is not empty.  it has a single message from html template.  single-step-checkout works!!!